# Is it possible to create a computer without sequential circuits?

Tags: transistors, computers

Do computers (or FSMs) **absolutely** need sequential logic, or can it be done theoretically without?

This seems impossible. Any proof of why it's not the case? (Showing that there can be no memory without sequential logic, and that FSMs need memory?)...

EDIT: I redefine computer to mean a Turing-complete system.

Comment: Arguably an unclocked ripple through device is not sequential per se - it just happens that sequentiality happens. Building something of any size using async logic shows you why clocking is used. Dave will probably query my above suggestion. If he does he's probably right :-).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want to call a "computer".

There are two kinds of logic circuits, combinatorial and sequential. Combinatorial circuits have outputs that are strictly a function of their current inputs, while sequential circuits employ feedback so that their output can be a function of both their current inputs and their past history — in other words, they have "memory".

Now, would you consider a circuit that had no memory to be a useful "computer"? Most people would not.

---

A computer is just a very large FSM, and *by definition* an FSM has memory. So any circuit that does not have memory is not an FSM.

Comment: Okay, so the implementation of a Turing Machine necessarily requires sequential circuits, since it requires memory. It wasn't quite sure about the definition of sequential and of memory. It seems that memory implies sequential, so this solves the question.

Comment: A digital computer is just a very large FSM, but there are also analog computers.

Comment: @ThePhoton: Yes, there are analog computers, but the concept of feedback and memory (e.g., integration and differentiation) is still the distinguishing feature that makes them useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible to make some types of computer without using synchronous digital logic.

The reason an op-amp is called an [operational amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier) is because it was originally the building block of the [electronic analog computer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_computer#Electronic_analog_computers). The op-amp is "Operational" in the sense of performing mathematical operations such as addition, multiplication, integration, and differentiation.

Programming an analog computer consists of

1. determining the mathematical equations to model the system being solved,
2. converting those equations into analog circuits, with each operation performed by an operational amplifier
3. switch the machine on and let the output settle to the solution value

Note that I specified *electronic* analog computer -- the definition of analog computer doesn't necessarily imply that it has to use electricity or electronics. Any device that solves a problem by means of an analogy (or analoque) is technically an analog computer.

Comment: An example of an ancient mechanical analog computer is the >2100-year-old [Antikythera Mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism)

Comment: Is it Turing-complete?

Comment: An analog computer is not necessarily "Turing-complete" -- this is an older class of computing machinery. There's no software and not necessarily any memory, so it doesn't directly map to a Turing machine. All that is required to make an analog computer, is that the laws of physics are exploited to solve an analogue of the real problem of interest.

Comment: Ah - I see your edit. This may be beyond the scope of what you're asking.